# How to write spec for concern

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a concern below. what i am doing is i am mapping the column from a table that has values 0, 1, 2 and returning strings for those in JSON. Can someone guide me how can i write unit test cases for it?

```
module User
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def user_mapping(user_in_number)
      user_hash = {
        '0'=> 'Support',
        '1'=> 'Developer',
        '2'=> 'Business Analyst'
      }.freeze
        user_hash[user_in_number]
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For any module you can do this:

```
subject = Class.new do
  include User
end.new

assert subject.user_mapping('0'), 'Support'
```

`Class.new` creates an [anonymous class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new), the block is evaluated in the context of the anonymous class, so acting like the body of a regular class.

Then create an instance of the anonymous class and call the methods as defined by the included module.

By the way the actual method does not need to assign so many vars:

```
UserMap = {
    '0'=> 'Support',
    '1'=> 'Developer',
    '2'=> 'Business Analyst'
  }.freeze

def user_mapping(user_in_number)
  UserMap.fetch(user_in_number)
end
```

`fetch` will raise if the given key is not found.

I'd might also reconsider the name `User` for a module, will you never need a `User` class...